# TFS 2017 Upload Extension The Extension Already Exists

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Working with an on-prem version of TFS 2017.  I've written a VSIX extension to add some domain specific tasks to our build process.

First time I uploaded, TFS complained about the manifest version not matching the task version.  I fixed this, rebuilt my VSIX and attempted to upload again.  I now get the error that "The Extension Already Exists".  Looking through the list of extensions, my extension does not appear.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the ID of your extension? Check it in vss-extension.json file. Try to change the ID and try again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the same extension has already been there, you need to remove it first.

Please try to filter the extensions by updated time (clicking the **Updated** column), the extensions uploaded recently will be displayed on top. Find the extension, then remove it and upload the fixed one again.

If the uploaded extension still not displayed there, just try to clean the client caches (including both TFS and Browser), then try it again.

- TFS:    `C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\{version}\Cache`
- Browser, IE for example (based on your settings) :

  `C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`

[image]